# Rails: Mounting engine inside engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I have got two engines A and B. A and B are already mounted in Application C.

```
Mount A::Engine => "/a"
MOUNT B::Engine => "/b"
```

Now I have third engine D which is admin engine.

```
Mount D::Engine => "/d"
```

Now as a admin I want a route for engines A and B from my admin engine D, i.e. **"/d/a"** or **"/d/b"**, through this i can access all paths of D

For this I am again mounting to engine A and B to D.

Is this the correct approach to do this.

Also I will like to know what problems can occur mounting a rails engine inside a rails engine, if any?

Thanks

Paritosh

Comment: Hi @Paritosh! Do you have any experience with this now? I am facing the same.. Thanks in advance!